# Swift Programming UIButtons

Tags: swift, uibutton, system, self

Im relatively new to the swift language and I am having a difficult time with creating a button. I have created a new file as a UIButton, so how would I change the button type using "self"?

for example..

```
import UIKit

class LoginButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect){

        super.init(frame: frame)


        self.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
// Above is where I need the button type as "System"

        self.enabled = true
        self.setTitle("Log in", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.addTarget(self, action: "logInPressed", forControlEvents:    UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func logInPressed(){
        println("log in")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to subclass UIButton? In most use cases, one uses UIButton directly and does not subclass it.

The buttonWithType() method you reference is a class method (not an instance method). You call it as UIButton.buttonWithType(type) which returns an instance of a UIButton so configured. You can't change the type after you instantiate the button; however, several methods are available for modifying the look of the button after you instantiate.

To add a brown border of size 2.0 to your button, you could add the following code:

```
    myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
    myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Comment: I guess I should've just asked other means of modifying the look of the button. In the subclass, without the buttonWithType() method, it compiles and runs just fine. The look of the button is just text, no border or anything. It is its default look. What are some methods to change the look of the button?

Comment: You can change several properties such as the titleColor per state and the backgroundColor. Checkout the UIButton documentation as well as the super classes along its inheritance line. Also you can grab the button's layer to configure a border if desired along with other properties.